# Use of arguments with property.deleter

Tags: python, properties

I'm trying to define a property `deleter` with a parameter for an attribute of `Character` class as follows:

```
class Character(object):
    _status = None

    @property
    def status(self):
        """ Return _status if it exists or False if not."""
        return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, status_value):
        """
        Receive the status and the duration(continous or not) and add
        it for the _status.
        """
        if not self._status:
            self._status = []

        self._status.append(status_value)

    @status.deleter
    def status(self, status_value):
        """
        Delete the specified object from the _status list.
        """
        status = [value for value in self._status
                  if status_value in value.keys()]
        if status:
            self._status.remove(self._status.index(status[0]))
```

I'm trying to delete a specific object from the status.

```
>>>a = Character()
>>>a.status = 'Test'
```

Would return a list with 1 element:

```
>>>a.status
['Test']
```

If i set the status again, the old value persists and new one is added to the list:

```
>>>a.status = 'Dazed'
>>>a.status
['Test', 'Dazed']
```

As well I want to delete only a specific value from the list:

```
>>>del a.status('Dazed')
```

And the expected result should be:

```
>>> a.status
['Test']
```

The problem is that hen I try:

```
del a.status('Dazed')
```

The following error occurs:

```
SyntaxError: can't delete function call
```

Is there any way to use arguments with a `property.deleter`?

Comment: Why would there be? What are you trying to achieve with the parameter - a conditional `del`? Also, please put a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code in the question itself.

Comment: Added a minimal example, hope it helps now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is odd behaviour you are trying to create, and would likely trip up users of your class. I certainly wouldn't expect:

```
self.status = "happy"
```

to *add* the new string to an existing list.

As far as I'm aware there is no way to pass an argument to a `@property.deleter`.

A better approach might be to make the `character.status` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) (I am assuming that you meant this to be an *instance attribute*, but this all stands for *class attributes* too):

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, ..., status=None):
        if status is None:
            self.status = set()
        else:
            self.status = set(status)
        ...

conan = Character(..., status=("happy", "cold"))

conan.status.add("tired")

conan.status.remove("happy")
```

One advantage of a `set` is that it prevents duplicates. Also, it provides for very fast membership tests (e.g. `if "warm" in conan.status:`) and you can find out if two `Character` instances have any of the same `status` easily:

```
if conan.status.intersection(other_character.status):
```

Comment: Very well pointed. I'll stick will set and the behavior described is a good approach to follow. Ty!