# How to decorate a list with deleter

Tags: python, list, inheritance, decorator

I am creating decorator to a list to set, get, and delete values. But the `deleter` decorator is working. when I call `del object[key]`, it doesn't actually do what I expect (`print('dellllllll')`).

```
class ListProperty:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._l = []
        
    @property
    def l(self):
        return self._l
    
    @l.setter
    def l(self, value):
        self._l.append(value)
        print('settttttttt')
        
    @l.deleter
    def l(self, key):
        del self._l[key]
        print('dellllllll')
        
ob = ListProperty()
print(ob.l)
ob.l = 5
print(ob.l)
ob.l = 100
print(ob.l)
del ob.l[0]
print(ob.l)
```

What am I missing in calling `del`

Comment: I don't think you can get argument `key` on deleter

Comment: You need to delete `obj.l` for the deleter to trigger, `obj.l[0]` points to the int inside the list. Of course that throws an error because your deleter expects a `key` argument. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371143/use-of-arguments-with-property-deleter) suggests it might not be possible to pass that, but it's pretty old now.

Comment: Yes, I found that, I can't pass the key calling del(ob.l).

Comment: Does your expected behavior include passing the key as an argument?

Comment: yes, to delete a certain element. and also, I need the same behavior when deleting all elements using del [:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't pass key on deleter because it expects a argument not a key.

in alternative way you can use this :

```
class ListProperty:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._l = []
        
    @property
    def l(self):
        return self._l
    
    @l.setter
    def l(self, value):
        self._l.append(value)
        print('settttttttt')

    @l.deleter
    def l(self):
        self._l = []
        print('deleted all')
        
    def pop(self, index):
        self._l.pop(index)
        print('dellllllll')
        
ob = ListProperty()
print(ob.l)
ob.l = 5
print(ob.l)
ob.l = 100
print(ob.l)
ob.pop(0)
print(ob.l)
del ob.l
print(ob.l)
```